# WebDriver+TestNG+Eclipse, Failing of Assertion in Try block doesn't pass the debugger to catch block

Tags: selenium, webdriver, java, testng, eclipse

Please see a simplified code below

```
public class testClass   
{
    static WebDriver driver;

    @Test
    public void Checking()
    {
        driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get("http://xyz.com");
        try 
        {
            Assert.assertEquals("Hello", "Not Hello");
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
           System.out.println("Fail" + e.getMessage());
        }
        System.out.println("just to check");
    }
}
```

While debugging the code, once the Assertion fails in try block it ask for 'Source' to attach for testNG. see the screenshot below:

[image: Attach the source] and then I added the source with the help of an eclipse plugin. Now when I start debugging and if the Assertion in try block fails then controll passed to the attached source (invoker.class) and does not return to the catch block ever.

Please suggest what shall I do in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case if you really want to catch your assertion failures, you can try and use following:

```
catch (AssertionError e) {
      //Your code to execute when an assertion fails.
}
```

For detail explanation you can refer the following answer:

 https://stackoverflow.com/a/29672257/3406534

Answer (score 1):

**Assertion :**

- Assert is implemented to verify expected and actual result.
- If Assert failed, It will terminate the script and it will not execute further code/test or any other block

**Try & Catch blocks :**

- Try and Catch blocks are used mainly to take action if errors & exception which might occur during execution
- Just provision to handle those error and exceptions in scripts/codes

**Back to your Question:**

- In your case, assert failed. Now it will terminate program to be executed further
- So its not going to execute catch block at assert is neither error nor exception

Answer (score 0):

You can try below structure in your `@Test` part:

```
try {
    assertEquals("Leave a Reply ", driver.findElement(By.id("reply-title")).getText());
} catch (Error e) {
    verificationErrors.append(e.toString());
}
Thread.sleep(6000);
```